# What is wrong with inference generic types

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, typescript-generics

I wrote a function wrapper (`callApi`), which is adding automatically some fields to params passed to the wrapped function (`service`). And trying to infer a short version of the type of params passed in the wrapped function, to use this typing when calling wrapper (see the last expression `callApi`).

Typing should highlight the error when a user passes some different parameter and should allow passing of all params from wrapped function (`service` in the example)

[Here is playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

```js
type RequiredParams = {
    requiredParam?: string;
};

type ApiFunc<Params, Returned> = (
    params?: Omit<Params, 'requiredParam'>,
) => Promise<Returned>;

export type CallApiFunc = <Returned, Params extends RequiredParams>(
    func: ApiFunc<Params, Returned>,
    params?: Omit<Params, 'requiredParam'>,
) => Promise<Returned>;

const callApi: CallApiFunc = (
    func, 
    params, 
) => {
    return func({
      ...params,
      requiredParam: 'somevalue-maybe-auth-token'
    });
};

const service = function ({arg} : {arg: number, requiredParam: string}) {
  return null;
}

callApi(service, {
  arg: 3, // Should not be error
  // test: 'ohoh', // Should be error
});
```

Comment: You probably omit the requiredParam to make sure the implementation of the service function has to include it. But for the callApi function, you don't want the user to set it. I assume in your real use case you set the requiredParam urself inside callApi or somewhere else. If I'm correct, why do you want to call func(param) on the reduced params and not on the full params? And if I'm not correct, what is the actual use case?

Comment: @MircoS. Yes, right, sorry, missed this detail. I update the example. So that in real use case it serves as an auth token, which is added by default to any API call inside `callApi` function. 
But actually, I want to call `callApi` with reduced params as a second argument, so that it can be later fulfilled with `requiredParam` (auth token) and call to `service` with full params.

So to be clear, once again, the second parameter of `callApi` function should have reduced type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the compiler doesn't accept `service` as the input of `callApi` is this line `func: ApiFunc<Params, Returned>`. You want the `service` function to be the original one with the full parameters and not something different where specific arguments are omitted. You only want to omit arguments for the `params`-arg of callApi. I would model your types like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXAlgJwgEwAoENU4FsBnKAXigG8AoKWqdJNTXfAgLiiOFWQDsBzANxUAvsKqhIUAPIFkwAHIB7XgFECYUAB4WhIgBooAaQggSEAB7AIvDCS48BUAD5ReiAgCMIqF5xBeSgA2AHxkUADWpkoAZjJywDp4eoYmZmGW1rYkvBAAbj40dAD8bvmFdFAcsvJaFPQIKOjYyeyc3Hz8UCKppkQh4jGIvADGwMgqUCM4QUEAgmDIWnDAiKi5GIa6xFCZNnawjUwtrP0AFEW0Q6McZ3j8RBzbRACUZGEraxv6l1BgrURitUEso1BptM9DAByBhNZitKEhH4vDifdaYSi-EYqLgNRjNZ7haiVSqw47bDhQohKAj5GaICAAWgIOBA3kZOEQwAAFozgEoorwoT8SXQAHQS-6nEV0ERQHAkZ7iUkQVbrKDXEZnMkEgEvYQiKhUbG8XFEHx5ZAjaDkTXjSZ3VAPDj1e4cdxeHyCPFwk6EDgOTrdN7EujoNW8KBYVA05DmsXoalBApndyzfWicQms0Wq0QABM4TtE0jjudlB95NaAY6ThEId+4a+UZjcnjieCKbTQQzYiN2eAUE8iCIfAgRCIAGEFTapjN5oszubUJbrYZQ7Q3VAAMyGAD0e6gAGVuUpEEEMG4lIPvLtUDHUL8D1BrFxKUpT9zhVBnyezxeh2gHwH1EDNjRxG8RzHCdp3NQtyGmWYFmQJdc2tfN11+Ldd1A71nwwJRxyFQcAHclFQCJ+wgocoNyGCZ23cJEIXFDl1XAt9R-Q8yIoogqCAA):

```js
type RequiredParams = {
    requiredParam: string;
};

type OmitNonEmpty<Params, Keys extends string | number | symbol> = keyof Omit<Params, Keys> extends never
    ? never
    : Omit<{ requiredParam: string }, Keys>;

function callApi<Returned, Params extends RequiredParams>(
    func: (args: Params) => Returned,
    params?: OmitNonEmpty<Params, 'requiredParam'>,
): Returned {
    const requiredParams = {
        requiredParam: 'somevalue-maybe-auth-token',
        ...params,
    } as Params;

    return func(requiredParams);
}

const service = function (args: { arg: number; requiredParam: string }) {
    return Promise.resolve(null);
};

const service2 = function (args: { requiredParam: string }) {
    return Promise.resolve(null);
};

const businessCase = callApi(service, {
    arg: 3, // Should not be error
    // test: 'ohoh', // Should be error
});

const businessCase2 = callApi(service2, {
    arg: 3,
}); // doesn't work

const businessCase3 = callApi(service2); // works
```

This part hits a limitation of typescript:

```
const requiredParams = {
    requiredParam: "somevalue-maybe-auth-token",
    ...params
} as Parameters<typeof func>[number];
```

Typescript won't fully evaluate the type of Omit<Params, 'requiredParam'> until `callApi` is actually used, and the generic `Param` is replaced with a real type. But since the definition of `const requiredParams` is made before `callApi` is used typescript won't recognize that `RequiredParams & Omit<Params, 'requiredParam'>` is equal to `Params extends RequiredParams`. Thats why we have to typecast here.

Comment: Though typecast is not very good thing generally, but in this case, I think it's harmless, since we are confident, that params will be extended version of `RequiredParams`. Many thanks. But I find out, that my comment in the above thread also makes sense here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66698727/what-is-wrong-with-inference-generic-types?noredirect=1#comment117909516_66701204 (please, open the link in new tab to move to the comment anchor)

Comment: You can't use the normal Omit if you want that behavior. I updated the example with a OmitNonEmpty type.

Comment: I've also removed the "?" from your original definition of type RequiredParams = {requiredParam: string;};, because the type makes more sense if requiredParams is not optional. In case you don’t need to enforce requiredParam on the services anymore, the other answers make more sense.

Comment: In the end, I've modified the solution a bit. I retained the type definition separated, since it's used in another part of the code, and also retained typecast as it was, but had to use `as unknown` first, for some reason. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problems

`callApi` serves as a wrapper around some function `func`.  We call `callApi` with an incomplete set of `params`, and those params are augmented with `{requiredParam: string}` before calling the `func`.

The error that you are having right now:

> Argument of type '{ requiredParam: "somevalue-maybe-auth-token"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Omit<Params, "requiredParam">'.`

Is due to a mistake in the definition of `ApiFunc`.  This the function that we call *after we've added `requiredParam`*, so its params type should be `Params` instead of `Omit<Params, 'requiredParam'>`.

After fixing that, we get a different error:

> Argument of type '{ requiredParam: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Params'.
>
> '{ requiredParam: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Params', but 'Params' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'RequiredParams'.

This one is because you have made it such that `params` is optional and could be `undefined` even if the generic type parameter `Params` has required properties.  So we cannot ensure that we are passing all of the necessary arguments to `func`.

But we're also not getting good type inference on your example with `callApi(service`.  So I would switch up the typings a bit and use `func` as the generic.

#### Solution

This is actually all that you need:

```
const callApi = <F extends (params: any) => any> (
    func: F,
    params: Omit<Parameters<F>[0], 'requiredParam'>, 
): ReturnType<F> => {
    return func({
      ...params,
      requiredParam: 'somevalue-maybe-auth-token'
    });
};
```

- The first argument is a function `F`  which has one argument: `F extends (params: any) => any`
- The second argument is the argument of `F` without the param that we are adding: `Omit<Parameters<F>[0], 'requiredParam'>`
- The return type is the same as the return type of `F`: `ReturnType<F>`.

You get an error if you use `callApi` on `service` with no arguments or with extra arguments, but you are able to call it just fine with the correct `arg`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/weeraw)

Comment: Thanks for an exhaustive explanation. And yet the solution won't work correctly if `params` type consists only `requiredParam`. That means, when `Omit<Parameters<F>[0], 'requiredParam'> ` will be computed, `params` will be typed as `{}` and compiler will not show error, if some unused fields will be passed in the `service`.

Comment: What I mean is: ```const service = function ({arg} : { requiredParam: string}) {
  return new Promise(() => null);
}``` will break type check on actual `callApi` call

Answer (score 1):

As a supplementary answer to [Linda's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701204/11407695) addressing the concern that the `{}` type is compatible with objects with any number of arbitrary-typed properties:

---

`{}` type is very broad* due to the structural nature of TypeScript's type system. Contrary to the normal intuition, it does not mean an "empty object", but an unconstrained object type. Thus, when one passes extra properties, the compiler is fine with it.

Now, this is trivially solved by checking if an *unconstrained* object type is assignable to our *constrained* type (`Omit<Parameters<F>[0]`). This will only happen if they are one and the same, therefore, the true branch of a checker should be `never`:

```ts
{} extends Omit<Parameters<F>[0], 'requiredParam'> ? never : Omit<Parameters<F>[0], 'requiredParam'>
```

Let's test the updated type:

```ts
const callApi = <F extends (params: any) => any> (
    func: F,
    params: {} extends Omit<Parameters<F>[0], 'requiredParam'> ? never : Omit<Parameters<F>[0], 'requiredParam'>, 
): ReturnType<F> => {
    return func({
      ...params,
      requiredParam: 'somevalue-maybe-auth-token'
    });
};

const service2 = function ({ arg } : { arg: number, requiredParam: string }) {
  return Promise.resolve(arg);
}

callApi(service2, {}); //Property 'arg' is missing in type '{}'

callApi(service2, {
  arg: 3, // OK
  test: 'ohoh', // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'test' does not exist
});

callApi(service2, {
  arg: 3, //OK
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGAbRBBADgSxgXhgHgDEYBTADymLABMIYAKNeAJ3gFsIAuGeMATwEocAPm58RdAFAxpMAGYBXMMC4EANFJmMW7LgG8AviXKUaMAPKsMUPAAVmbYhSYRCQgNoAGALqqYAciZiAEd5DECqO20-EQB%20GDBiADdiJhguCytbe1ZHFJcCd29fAODQ8Mi2aN8Jfi4AJUd5JjAAFV40YldhGF0NaUCoJrA5RWA6XpkZADoZrTYIdUn%200rDiCOyuPwgQHMSkeWIAWlZ4XgAjI-h5KAALQ6gQAGtKPz6YfX4Abgl9b4lQSCwCApRIYYDEHAjJRQDDgei6d5pHowQIhVbrbRcaBMDBgADm70EExRjWaMBsTB2GGBU0C20QyToYHkyC%20Pwk-yQqEwdGBTFB4N8CMJnxgAHoxSgmHj5DkwLAQLIYFB2hC-AY-DBqfEQLB4BAIBg8WB4GdEBCHjA5jknDBFcrVf4EskmK9-uBoDA%20QLiAAmSEKaGw4bjbjSxF6MN4rjM1gXJi%20VFlNYVVhYqA4-GEnoaAZDcmUyw0ukgBnEOjMPFs-QchDIdAYXkgsF%20oUfUUSikgDpMFX%20Sua7VFw1Z3EOjr%20DW1rkNpv8lu%20oUaStcADMvgl5gA0hoKNBNiAboe-BuxeYzgArYjAWCIKwpJAwE68O1gRAviAdYAYWQvx5gEAAHdhjQSkexhYgFlEKh-D3KBNSoEBIJ1WAyGpKAfjZTl6x5b0FyXaQVxgddxTFMwd3bIA)

---

* Note that the empty object literal (when you assign an empty object to a variable, for example, `const obj = {};`) truly means an empty object due to excess property checks in object literals.